# how to read and modify image file stored at FTP server using java

Tags: java, ftp

I want to make thumbanials of image stored on ftp server but i am getting following exception:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

code :

```
   String curr_input_img = null;
   BufferedImage original_img = null;
   String finalfolderpath = AppConstants.FTP_PATH + path;
   String thumbailpath = finalfolderpath + "/thumbnail";
   FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
   try{
   client.connect("188.148.12.58");
   client.login("root", "admin123");
   boolean result = client.changeWorkingDirectory(finalfolderpath);
   FTPFile[] ftpfiles = client.listFiles();
   if (result == true) {
      client.makeDirectory("thumbnail");
       for (FTPFile ftpfile : ftpfiles) {
          curr_input_img = ftpfile.getName();
                    original_img = ImageIO.read(new File(curr_input_img)); // read original image
            }
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
   }
```

Comment: check for the permissions . url , credentials and the network connectivity

Comment: it does not have read and write permission....so how to read it..?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to read file from local file sistem.

You need to download file, edit it and upload back.

You can use `FTPClient.retrieveFileStream()` to get `InputStream` and then feed it to `ImageIO.read`

Comment: each file is so large almost 50mb so i have such mininum 100 files so...?

Comment: If you do not have 50 mb on your hard drive try to find library that can work with files as Input/Output streams.